# Paypal Cancel Subscription issue

Tags: paypal, payment, subscription

I've created a subscribe button on my site using simple form as below.

```
<form name="mypaypalform" id="mypaypalform" action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="item_number" value="123">
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick-subscriptions">
<input type="hidden" name="no_note" value="1">
<input type="hidden" name="notify_url" value="http://dev2.pw/dev/payment-confirm/">
<input type="hidden" name="return" value="http://dev2.pw/dev/payment-confirm/">
<input type="hidden" name="business" value="leonard@kwikcost.com">
<input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="Subscribe to Expert"> <input type="hidden" name="src" value="1">
<input type="hidden" name="a3" value="0.01">
<input type="hidden" name="p3" value="1">
<input type="hidden" name="t3" value="M">
<input type="hidden" name="srt" value="2">
<input type="hidden" name="bn" value="PP-SubscriptionsBF:btn_subscribeCC_LG.gif:NonHostedGuest">
<input type="submit" style="cursor:pointer;" class="centro_viewbuy" value="Subscribe us">
</form>
```

I've set notify_url in it. Its works fine. When someone subscribe to my site. It does come to my notify page and then i store transaction details in my database. Now my problem is when some of my subscriber press "Cancel Subscription" from his paypal account. I need to update my database with "Cancel" status. How i can do this ? 
I dont want to use IPN settings notification URL. because i'll be using one paypal account for many of my sites. I want paypal to notify me on the same page where it sends me notification when some one was subscribed.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

Without using IPN, the only way you would be able to keep track of this is to have your profile id's stored in a database.  Then set your system up to periodically (could use a cron job) to make a GetRecurringPaymentsProfileDetails API call to get the status of the profile.  Then either set it to cancelled or remove it completely from your database if the profile is cancelled.  Then just have your system run a loop to check all of the profiles.

Comment: Does this still work? I just tried doing this and received this error from the API: "Subscription Profiles not supported by Recurring Payment APIs." Is there a different API that can accomplish the profile lookup?